# Continuity of a function at $x^*$ implies that a property $P(f(x^*))$ holds for points near $x^*$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, optimization, proof-explanation, dynamical-systems

I'm working through *Numerical Optimization* by Nocedal and Wright, and I'm having trouble with some of its proofs that seem too handwavy to me. Take the first theorem for example:

> Theorem: If $x^∗$ is a local minimizer and $f$ is continuously differentiable
>   in an open neighborhood of $x^∗$, then $∇ f (x^∗) = 0$.
>
> Proof (excerpt): Suppose for contradiction that $∇ f (x^∗) \neq 0$.
>   Define the vector $p = −∇ f (x^∗)$ and note that $$p^T ∇ f (x^∗) = − \|
>  f (x^∗)\|^2 < 0.$$ Because $∇ f$ is continuous near $x^∗$, there is a
>   scalar $T > 0$ such that $$\forall t ∈ [0, T ], p^T ∇ f (x^∗ + tp) < 0 $$

Similarly, in another proof (second-order necessary condition), the author assumes $∇^2 f (x^∗)$ is not positive definite (so $\exists p\in\mathbb{R}^n, p^T ∇^2 f (x^∗)p < 0$), and uses the (assumed) continuity of  $∇^2 f$ near $x^*$ to conclude the existence of a scalar $T > 0$ such that $\forall t ∈ [0, T ], p^T ∇^2 f (x^∗+tp)p < 0$.

On the surface, the argument roughly seems to be:
if $f$ is continuous at $x^*$, and a certain property $P$ holds for $f(x^*)$, then $P$ holds for $f(x)$ when $x$ is near $x^*$. But of course this is not true in general  (for example, take $f$ to be $f(x)=x$, $x^*=0$, $P(f(x^*))$ to be $f(x^*)\geq0$).

I would appreciate some help justifying such statements as "Because $∇ f$ is continuous near $x^∗$, there is scalar $T > 0$ such that $\forall t ∈ [0, T ], p^T ∇ f (x^∗ + tp) < 0 $", specifically using the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a continuous function in a metric space (what's the appropriate $\epsilon$ here?).

Comment: Well, the property used in the proof isn't just some general property. Consider the function $g : x\mapsto p^{\mathrm{T}}\nabla f(x)$. Due to the continuity of $\nabla f$ in a neighborhood of $x^*$ (I don't have the full context, so this is assumed from the provided proof excerpt) *and* the continuity of matrix multiplication, $g$ will be continuous, which will give you the final statement in the proof excerpt. The second proof is also omitting the (important but obvious) continuity of matrix multiplication.

Comment: I see; the continuity of $\nabla f(x)$ alone is not sufficient... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of this step is, if $\phi : X \to \Bbb{R}$ is continuous at a point $x_0 \in X$ and $\phi(x_0) < 0$, then there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $\phi(x) < 0$ for all $x \in B(x_0; \delta)$. I hope you can justfy why, for fixed $p$, and continuously differentiable $f$,
$$x \mapsto p^\top \nabla f(x)$$
is continuous.

To prove this lemma, take $\varepsilon = |f(x_0)| = -f(x_0) > 0$. By the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity, we know that there must exist some $\delta > 0$ such that
\begin{align*}
d(x, x_0) < \delta &\implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \varepsilon = -f(x_0) \\
&\implies f(x_0) < f(x) - f(x_0) < -f(x_0) \\
&\implies 2f(x_0) < f(x) < 0.
\end{align*}
Hence, $f(x) < 0$ for all $x \in B(x_0; \delta)$.

Comment: For the continuity of $p^⊤ ∇f(x)$, a simple application of Cauchy-Schwartz inequality shall suffice, right?

Comment: C-S is what you'd use, yes. You're composing the map $x \mapsto p^\top x$ (continuous by C-S) and $x \mapsto \nabla f(x)$ (continuous by assumption).